# Break string into fields

Tags: php, mysql, regex

I have a string input using PHP that look like this:

```
Log,,t1,12.12:t2,20.23:t3,30.00:t4,50.20:11.23
```

I want to save it into MySQL

```
field:reading
t1:12.12
t2:20.23
t3:30.00
t4:50.20
Temp:11.23
```

Can anyone give me an direction?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself?

Comment: Where does `field`, `reading` and `Temp` come from? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2):

Begin you have to parse to rows and columns

```
$string = 't1,12.12:t2,20.23:t3,30.00:t4,50.20:11.23';
$rows = explode(':', $string);
$table = array();
foreach(rows as $row) {
   $table[] = explode(',', $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex below:

```
if (preg_match_all('/[a-z]+\d+,\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+/i', $string, $matches) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```

The regex can be a bit simpler if each field will called "t+number":

```
if (preg_match_all('/t\d+,\d+\.\d+|\d+\.\d+/i', $string, $matches) {
    var_dump($matches[0]);
}
```